# como coletar retweets e replys de um usuário em ruby

Tags: ruby, api, twitter-api

Estou fazendo um trabalho e nele preciso coletar o número de retweets e replys de 10 tweets de um usuário do Twitter. No código já é possível coletar o número de seguidores e seguindo de usuários e fiz uma tentativa de coleta dos retweets de 10 tweets de cada usuário, mas ela não está dando certo.

```
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|

    config.consumer_key = "xxx"
    config.consumer_secret = "yyy"
    config.access_token = "zzz"
    config.access_token_secret = "www"

     client.search(":(", :lang => "pt", :result_type => "recent", :exclude => "retweets").take(10).collect do |tweet|
       dif = tweet.user.followers_count - tweet.user.friends_count
       puts "Name: #{tweet.user.screen_name} - Follower: #{tweet.user.followers_count} - Following: #{tweet.user.friends_count} - Difference: #{dif}"
       tweet.user.search(:result_type => "recent").take(10).collect do |tweet|
          count = tweet.retweet_count
          puts "Retweets de 10 tweets: #{count}"
       end
     end
```

Como eu faço para conseguir coletar os retweets e replys?

Comment: Talvez você queira regerar os seus API secrets do Twitter…

Comment: Tem que ir atrás de ler a api do twitter